# Open Raspberry Pi Terminal via Terminal Command?

Tags: linux, terminal, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian OS 11.
I want to open another Terminal window via a command in an existing Terminal window.

What is the command to achieve this?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `lxterminal` command.
It will open up a new, clean terminal under the current user's name.